# Не работает форма. Php не видит переменные

Tags: php, html

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#main-form").submit(function() {
    var str = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/assets/php/sendform2.php",
      success: function() {
        $('.modal-form').css({
          opacity: '1',
          visibility: 'visible'
        });
        $('.modal-form2').css({
          display: 'block',
        });
        $('.modal-form1').css({
          display: 'none',
        });
      }
    });

    // event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
});
```

При отправке письма приходят, но без введенных данных. PHP не видит переменные.

```html
<form method="POST" class="form__container" id="main-form">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="name">Ваше имя:</label>
      <p><input type="text" placeholder="Имя" name="name" id="name"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="number">Ваш телефон:</label>
      <p><input type="text" placeholder="Телефон" name="phone" id="number"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="tariff">Выберите тариф:</label>
      <div class="tariff-container">
        <p>
          <select name="tariff" id="tariff" class="tariff">
            <option value="Быстрый старт">Быстрый старт</option>
            <option value="Продвинутый">Продвинутый</option>
            <option value="Профессиональный">Профессиональный</option>
          </select>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p class="label-p">Где с вами связаться:</p>
      <div class="modal__checkbox">

        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="email" checked/>
        <span>Email<i class="far fa-envelope"></i></span>
       </label>

        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="WhatsApp"/>
        <span>WhatsApp<i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></span>
       </label>

        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="Viber"/>
        <span>Viber<i class="fab fa-viber"></i></span>
       </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label for="message">Сообщение:</label>
      <p><textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Тематика вашего сайта, цели, пожелания."></textarea></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="submit" value="отправить" class="yell-btn uppercase">
      <p class="confidence">Нажимая кнопку, Вы принимаете <br><span>соглашение на обработку персональных данных</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```
 <?php>


$adminemail="nameless121312@yandex.ru";  // e-mail админа
$backurl1="http://mp-group";
// Принимаем данные с формы

$name=$_POST['name'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$tariff=$_POST['tariff'];
$messenger=$_POST['messenger'];
$message=$_POST['message'];

$msg="name:". $name . "
phone:" . $phone . "
tariff:" . $tariff . "
messenger:" . $messenger . "
message:" . $message . "";

mail("$adminemail", "Сообщение от $name", "$msg");

print "<script language='Javascript'><!-- 
function reload() {location = \"$backurl1\"
}; setTimeout('reload()', 100); 
//--></script> 
<p>Сообщение отправлено!</p>";
exit;
```

Comment: а где у вас action в форме ? куда вы ее отправляете ?

Comment: Отправка происходит через ajax. Забыл прикрепить js код

Comment: так вы же в аяксе не каких данных на сервер не отправляете 
var str = $(this).serialize();
и дальше str не используется

Comment: нужно в аяксе добавить data:ваши переменные,

Comment: пример - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6960586/4419684

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#main-form").submit(function() {

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/assets/php/sendform2.php",
      data:$(this).serialize()
      success: function() {
        $('.modal-form').css({
          opacity: '1',
          visibility: 'visible'
        });
        $('.modal-form2').css({
          display: 'block',
        });
        $('.modal-form1').css({
          display: 'none',
        });
      }
    });

    // event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
});
```